# SQL selection - adding NULL to a not in

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good Afternoon,

I have a when clause in a query that is meant to check if an object is listed in a valid location, if it isn't the next part of the when clause sets a value of "Not available"

```
when (LocationId not In (8,4,18) or LocationId IS not null)
            then 'Not Available'
            else (more case when clauses to determine availability)
```

was what I was using until I realised whilst I would get my available results only from locations 8,4 and 18. I DID want Null locations to fall into the next steps of the checks.

How would I best add the Null to the not in? I realise it would seem easier to have a (in(8,4,18) or is null) and switch my then and else values around. The only problem there is I have around 8 other nested  case whens after this to check other things along the way and it makes me cry thinking of rearranging the tree.

Comment: Does that make sense? `or LocationId IS not null` includes all LocationIds. That makes the first `NOT IN` pointless. You should show some sample records and a desired result.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, like Tim said, it's an odd statement. However, you can catch null values with when isnull(LocationId, 9) not in (8, 4, 18) (Or replace null with 8 if you want it in the results.)

Comment: Thanks guys I replaced the code with 
'when (LocationId In (8,4,18) or LocationId IS null)'
and switched my then and else cases around, the tree was simpler from that point than I thought. Thanks for the trouble though :)

Answer (score 1):

NULL is never found in an IN list (because its value is "unknown"). So simply removing your `or LocationId IS not null` solves the problem:

```
when (LocationId not In (8,4,18))
then 'Not Available'
else (more case when clauses to determine availability)
```

In other words: The opposite to `when (LocationId In (8,4,18) or LocationId IS null)` is `when (LocationId not In (8,4,18) and LocationId IS not null)`which is the same as `when (LocationId not In (8,4,18))`.

Comment: Thanks, I went with when (LocationId In (8,4,18) or LocationId IS null) and flipped my results over.